# Dual boot GRUB menu no longer appears after moving computer

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, windows-10

I've had Windows 10 and Kubuntu on dual-boot, working perfectly, for half a year. Yesterday I moved my table to the other side of the room, which required me to unplug everything, and when I turned on the computer I noticed the GRUB menu didn't show up and I was booted directly to Kubuntu. I used to see a menu with 4 options (in this order): boot to Linux, booting options for Linux, boot to Windows, and booting options for Windows. Now it goes directly to Kubuntu, like it chose the first option instantaneously. Turning off the computer from Kubuntu causes a weird behaviour: it doesn't shut down immediately and instead spends like 1 minute acting as if it was rebooting before finally shutting down. Another weird behavior I have encountered is that when turning on, if I spam the arrow keys my computer keeps rebooting until I stop, when it boots to Kubuntu. I tried this because I remembered the GRUB menu chooses the first option (booting to Kubuntu) if it detects no input for 10 seconds and I thought that maybe the menu just wasn't displaying and with that I could stall it, but nope.

The only thing I did to my PC yesterday was unplugging every cable and plugging them in again. I have no idea what might have gone wrong. I am capable of seeing and accessing the files in my Windows 10 partition from Kubuntu.

EDIT: I posted the answer below.

Comment: VTC - problem was caused by an incorrect hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was while trying to fix some screen tearing. It turns out I had my monitor connected to the motherboard instead of the graphics card. I am clueless as to why this caused so much issue but it's completely fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

open /etc/default/grub with editor and check if your grub timeout is 0. if so change anything you like and run "(sudo) update-grub" in terminal.

Comment: Here's the contents of that file: ```GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""```

Comment: your conf seems okey to me. if you couldnt find any workaround you can try installing grub again.

Comment: I am worried of doing that because I don't know much about Linux yet and I wouldn't want dig a deeper hole. I can't remember if I updated anything that day but here's a picture of the grub-related packages I have on my installation: https://imgur.com/a/lpF46WQ

Comment: @AlbertoVilches Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`, run `sudo update-grub` and see if this helps.

Comment: @mook765 I just tried this and saw no difference. My computer seemed to reboot around 3 times when I tried to shut it down from Kubuntu. This didn't happen before.

Answer (score 0):

If one wants the GRUB menu to appear, then in /etc/default/grub instead of

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

one can use

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
```

I have this setting, with GRUB_TIMEOUT=15, and the result is the menu being displayed, while the timeout countdown is still observable on the bottom of the screen.